# When certain keyword is entered bot will not return message when using @client.event discord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So, im coding a discord bot. I'm trying to have it respond to a key word with saying for example "Pong!" for some reason this is not working. I have been trying solutions for an hour and i'm tyred. If anyone can help that would be great. All I want is for the bot to say pong when someone says ping as a keyword.
Here's the code.

```
# if anyone says keywords
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "Ping" in message.content:
        await ctx.send('Pong!')
```

Thanks
-Jake

Comment: You can't use `ctx` in an `message` event. Change it to `await message.channel.send("Pong!")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is very much clear.

#### Where is the error exactly?

The problem is in this statement:

```
await ctx.send('Pong!')
```

`ctx` is actually the context parameter that is passes when you use the `Command API` of the discord library. But as you are using simple `Client` you can really use it.

In this line:

```
async def on_message(message):
```

The parameter is `message` and this we are going to use it to send our message.

So it is much simple.

Just change the error statement, as mentioned above to:

```
await message.channel.send("Pong!")
```

This will solve your problem!

Thank You! :D